# refresh the registration page

Tags: html

I have directed from one registration html page to another 
If I press the back button in the toolbar the contents in that previous page should be refreshed.

Suggest me a solution

Comment: I think you need to refresh your question so we know exactly what you mean and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want't is for the data in the field to be different when the user goes back to it? To do this you need to put the default values into the page. If there is no value attribute in the elements, then the browser will fill them in by itself. So for example:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Some value" />
```

Next you need to make sure the page isn't cached. Try putting this in the header of the page:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to elaborate: what server side technology do you use to construct your HTML form? PHP, ASP, .Net, Ajax...?
Basically, if you don't use any server side caching mechanism, your only recourse is to cache data in a cookie, if you hope to see persistent data between HTML pages.

Comment: thanks for the response
im working with jsp and i will try working with the cookie

Comment: Actually, if you're working with JSP, you don't need a cookie - just render the page with the up-to-date data each time...